# User Login and Logout Activity log in Power BI

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, office365

Requirement is 1.user when login and logout in the Office365 system 2.Which application they have accessed. 3.How much time they spend in each application?

How to User login and Logout details get in the Power Bi from Office365?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach,

First you need to export Azure Active Directory logs to your log analytics workspace as directed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-integrate-activity-logs-with-log-analytics

Then using a blank M query, you ingest your log analytics data as directed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/powerbi